# Counting the number of elements associated with another value in R

Tags: r, dataset

For example, In a dataset, I have three groups as 1,2,3 and each group can either assign to 0 or 1. What is the code in R that allows me to count how many 0 assigned to group 1?

Comment: @akrun I am sorry, I am really new to R, can you explain a little bit more please.

Comment: Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to create a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what @akrun was presumably trying to explain in the comment:

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(grp=sample(3,300,replace = TRUE),val=rbinom(300,1,0.5))
```

This generates a data.frame with two columns, one for the group, the other for the value:

```
head(df1)
#  grp val
#1   1   1
#2   3   0
#3   2   1
#4   3   1
#5   3   1
#6   1   0
```

The function `table()` can be applied to see how many members of each group have a value of zero or one:

```
table(df1)
#   val
#grp  0  1
#  1 48 51
#  2 55 50
#  3 52 44
```

So, in this example, there are 48 entries with value 0 assigned to group 1.

---

Perhaps a more explicit way to obtain the specifically requested information could be to sum the number of entries that are equal to zero and which belong to group one in the data.frame `df1`:

```
sum(df1$val[df1$grp==1]==0)
#[1] 48
```